# Unit Test Error: REQUIRED_FIELD_MISSING, Required fields are missing: [Status, Priority]: [Status, Priority]

Tags: apex, winter18

As of Oct. 12, any unit tests we have in a Winter '18 org that create Tasks are failing with a message of:

```
REQUIRED_FIELD_MISSING, Required fields are missing: [Status, Priority]: [Status, Priority]
```

Field configurations do not require the fields, only the layouts do as per standard configuration. No changes were made to the unit tests or the metadata prior to this failure.

Comment: I was wondering why that just started cropping up. Glad I'm not the only one to experience it.

Comment: Our overnight run of unit tests in our 30 orgs produced this in 6 of the 8 orgs that were upgraded to Winter '18. A subsequent run ~6 hours later is not throwing the error, so it seems like it was an overnight anomaly that may no longer be present.

Comment: @AlwaysThinkin I've had this issue where I get the required field missing error on a specific field on a custom object. This field was deployed as a required field but was changes to not being required after a day. However, we're still getting this error once in a while on new records being inserted. I haven't been able to find out why this is happening. Please help if you have ideas as to what may be causing this. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently this was just some one-time error in orgs updated to Winter '18 on Oct 6. It did not affect our orgs updated on Oct 7.

We attempted to get Salesforce Support to investigate but decided to close the ticket rather than endure mindless questions for days on end. Their closing advice was typically mindless: "However please make sure that the priority and status fields are filled even when task records are created through code."